# Is the expression, “the difficulty Perry has had planting doubts” about Romney right?

Tags: verbs, meaning-in-context

There was the following sentence in the *New York Times* (September 24) article, titled “[Perry and Romney set clear lines of attack](http://www.nytimes.com/2011/09/25/us/politics/perry-and-romney-set-clear-lines-of-attack.html?pagewanted=all)”:

> “His (Rick Perry’s) shaky debate performance Thursday night in Florida underscored concerns among establishment Republicans and donors about his electability and his skills as a candidate on a national stage — and *the difficulty he has had planting serious doubts* about Mr. Romney. He also finished a distant second place in a weekend Florida straw poll."

I was arrested to the line, ‘His shaky debate performance underscored audience’s concerns about --- and *the difficulty he has had planting serious doubts*” about Mr. Romney.’

Is the expression, “have ＋_ing” like “He has had planting serious doubts” common English usage? Shouldn’t it be either ‘he has (had) planted,’ or “he has (had) been planting.” I’ve barely seen the expression “have (had)” directly followed by a gerund or a verb in progressive form.

Comment: You're misparsing because of the *has had*. It would mean much the same if you discard the word *has*. Perry *had difficulty [doing sth]*. The extra word *has* just adds a touch of "immediacy" in the sense that although it was in the past when he had the difficulties, he's either *still having them*, or is *currently affected by the fact of having had them in the past*.

Comment: ＠Fumble Fngers. In that case, don’t you need preposition, “in” before “planting,” i.e. “Perry had difficulty in doing something?” Is “I have difficulty understanding English grammar,” instead of “I have difficulty in understanding English grammar” or “It’s difficult to understand English grammar” all right, in the same token?

Comment: You can have *difficulty doing [sth]* the same as *difficulty* **in** *doing [sth]*. Often/usually we drop the *"in"* because it adds nothing - it's redundant. Your last *“It’s difficult to understand English grammar”* means exactly the same except it's in the passive voice (*you* aren't explicitly admitting to having a problem).

Comment: Can I say "I had difficulty paying the tuition?"

Comment: Absolutely (except the '?' should go *outside* the quotes because it's not part of what you're asking about, it's to indicate you're asking). You can also say *"I* **have** *had difficulty paying the tuition"*, which means much the same but brings the time nearer to the present (as before, either *still* having difficulties, or *only just recently* got things sorted out). We'd probably say *paying* **for** *the tuition*, or *paying the tuition* **fees**, but that's just nit-picking and your version isn't really incorrect, IMHO.

Comment: Locally (Toronto, Canada), "paying tuition" is the common usage. "paying tuition fees" is seen as needlessly formal/wordy, and "paying for tuition" instead connotes something more like "furnishing money with which I will pay my tuition".

Comment: @FumbleFingers. Thank you for your correction and detailed explanation of 'have' usage in present / past perfect tense. I had 'dificulty understanding' this at schoolhood, because we don't have future/ present / past perfect tense in our language. I obviously misplaced the question mark. That should be placed after" mark.

Comment: It can get worse! It could have been *...the difficulty he has been having planting serious doubts...* These are somewhat cumbersome constructions that you'd often try to avoid in writing, but people do use them quite a lot in speech. When you can say, for example, *he's* instead of *he has*, it makes things more manageable.

Answer (score 3):

It's correct, if obtuse. Think about it this way: *...(the difficulty he has had) (planting serious doubts)*. He has had difficulty planting serious doubts, and this is one of the concerns.

Comment: I wouldn't really say it's obtuse to double up *has had*. A little bit clumsy, perhaps, but we've all had reason to do it. Especially if you disguise the first one as **'ve** and put **and** in between them. Anyway, some people like [lots of hads](http://lumberjack.tumblr.com/post/908731653)

Comment: I had had quite a few *hads* before this myself.  :)

Comment: John, while James had had "had", had had "had had". "Had had" had had a better effect on the teacher.